# How does an ASIC Bitcoin miner work on a fundamental level?

Tags: asic, asicboost

I'd like to understand how ASIC miners are more efficient at mining bitcoin. Having a background in CS, how does the ASIC miner work on a binary level on the CPU and why is it so much faster?

Comment: Does https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12029/5406 or https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/16940/5406 perhaps answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

ASIC miners hash quicker with less electricity draw over time due to microprocessor chip advancements, ie J/TH efficiency. ASIC are only designed to do the SHA-256 algo, whereas CPUs and GPUs can be reprogrammable. In general ASIC advancements follow Moore's law.